# How to get internet connection status change call in cordova web app?

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications

I need to track users `android` mobile internet connection status change event call in my `cordova app`. I am trying to fetch new data from server according. Currently my **system throws errors when internet connection disabled**.
Please help.

Comment: Basically you need a wrapper for "reachability" which will throw a notification (callback) when inet is unreachable. This way you can set a class that will show the user a custom screen whenever there is no inet connection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should consider to catch and handle these errors.

You can use a cordova plugin for that, [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)